# pandas grouping and aggregating

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in the format below:

```
Timestamp            Column1    Column2   Column3
2018-01-01 00:00:01    5.7        4.0        2.0
2018-01-01 00:00:02    5.7        4.2        1.8
2018-01-01 00:00:03    4.9        5.1        5.5
2018-01-01 00:00:04    5.8        5.2        1.9
```

and so on. Essentially have data in second level granularity.
I am looking to summarize as follows:

```
Timestamp            Column1    Column2   Column3
2018-01-01 00:00       5.8        5.2       5.5
```

Essentially for every minute, I want to calculate the max value. Any value occurring between say

```
  2018-01-01 00:00:01 and 2018-01-01 00:00:59
```

needs to be included in the calculation and summarized as value for timestamp

```
 2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

I have tried (assuming df is the name of the dataframe) and pandas loaded as pd

```
 df=df.groupby(pd.Timestamp.floor(df['Timestamp'], freq='min')).max()
```

But this does not work.
Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Do `df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('1min').max().reset_index()`

Comment: Perfect Thanks! FYI...just got an error                                                     
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'                                                                    
 Which is solved by your other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272540/pandas-typeerror-only-valid-with-datetimeindex-timedeltaindex-or-periodindex?rq=1