# How to interpolate a series of python dataframes in one dictionary and save to another?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate multiple time-series of location data from multiple csv files. I have been able read in the csv files and save them to a dictionary of dataframes for each timeseries.

I am now looking to interpolate these time series. I have tried the code blow but am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

Python code:

```
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\drifters' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

drifters = {}

for idx, filename in enumerate(all_files,start=1):
    drifters["drifter{0}".format(idx)] = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, parse_dates={"date_time": ['Date', 'Time']})

drifters_interp = {}

for idx, (key,value) in enumerate(drifters.items(),start=1):
    drifters_interp["drifter{0}".format(idx)] = drifters[key].set_index('date_time').resample('2min').mean().interpolate('linear')
```

Is there a way to loop over one dictionary, interpolate, and save to another?

**EDITs**:

**Here is the full error:**

File "", line 12, in 
drifters_interp["drifter{0}".format(idx)] = drifters[key].set_index('date_time').resample('2min').mean().interpolate('linear')

File "C:\Users\nkj19blc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8096, in resample
offset=offset,

File "C:\Users\nkj19blc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1270, in get_resampler
return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)

File "C:\Users\nkj19blc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1436, in _get_resampler
"Only valid with DatetimeIndex, "

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

**A look in the drifters dictionary:**

[image]

**A look in one of the DataFrames:**

[image]

Comment: Which line raise the Exception? Can we get the full Exception?

Comment: Quick tip: When you have difficulties troubleshooting your errors, using functional programming, try to put your failing call on its own line. 1. You may discover that you were wrong about the origin of your error 2. it makes it easy to print/log before and after the failing code, thus making it easy to debug.

Comment: @FlorianFasmeyer thanks - I've uploaded the full error.

Comment: The error is raised by `resample`, not by `interpolate`. `set_index` seems to return something you did not expect. NB: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @FlorianFasmeyer yes it seems that way. I've tried using this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272540/pandas-typeerror-only-valid-with-datetimeindex-timedeltaindex-or-periodindex) but get the same error.

Comment: Can you show us your `'date_time'` column?

Comment: @FlorianFasmeyer I've added a picutre of the dictionary, and one of the dataframes

Answer (score 0):

After calling `set_index`, try to turn your DataFrame's index into a `DatetimeIndex`.

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, unit='s')
```

If this works, then you may want to make sure the columns you provide to `set_index` really is of type `pandas.Datetime`. Check your DataFrame with `DataFrame.dtypes`.

Comment: You were right. Due to some time-series having NaNs, the whole column was not being converted to datetime for certain data frames. I got around it by editing the second for loop to the following:

`for idx, (key,value) in enumerate(drifters.items(),start=1):
    drifter_df = drifters[key].dropna()
    drifter_df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(drifter_df['date_time']) 
    drifters_interp["drifter{0}".format(idx)] = drifter_df.set_index('date_time').resample('2min').mean().interpolate('linear')`

Thank you for your help.